# Tangent line computation in 3D point cloud

Tags: matlab, 3d, computer-vision, armadillo, photogrammetry

I am working on 3D reconstruction. I have a bench of 3D points(having x,y,z coordinates).  The question is given one specific 3D point p1 how can I find the tangent line passing through it?

Here are some of the steps I've tried so far:

step1)  I took points found inside a certain radius 'r' from p1

step2) Then I computed the co-variance matrix of those points found inside radius 'r'

step3) Then I computed the normal of that surface-segment(which is the vector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue).

*If I'm not wrong this approach is called Principal Component Analysis(PCA).

Now my question is how can I find the tangent line of that specific point p1 which is obviously orthogonal to the normal? if it works for one point p1 then I will iterate those steps to get the tangent line and normal of each point with respect to their corresponding neighbor points. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Do you mean tangent *plane*?

Comment: If you got a point and its normal, that is basically already a representation of the tangent plane: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html So what you want is only dependent on the data structure you are dealing with. As you are not specifying what this data structure is, we can't help you.